# Arabic is not rendered in the SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm storing the HTML Code in the SQL Server table and sending the email using asp.net by using the body from the SQL server table column.

**Sql Server Table**

```
Id    body_english  body_arabic
```

Here the Id is auto generated and the body is nvarchar(Max)

I'm storing the complete HTML code (listed below) so that I can use the body from SQL Server to send the email.

The main issue is when storing the HTML code in the body_arabic column, it is rendered as ??????

The body_english column is fine.

**HTML Document**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

</head>
<body>

<h1>مرحبا $$Username##</h1>
<p>هذه فقرة</p>
<p>مباشر</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help.

Comment: Is it just displayed wrongly in MSSSMS but when you retrieve the column you have right text? If not, how you store and retrieve that value?

Comment: How are you attempting to store the text? If you're doing it directly in a query, are you prefixing the string with an `N` to mark it as an nvarchar literal string? E.g. `INSERT INTO Table (body_arabic) VALUES (N'<!DOCTYPE html>...</html>')`

Comment: what is your DB collation ?

Comment: Latin1_General_CI_AI

Comment: @Adriano No, the same when I'm retrieving the body and sending the email. I'm also getting ???? as arabic in email

Comment: What's code you're using to **store** that text?

Comment: I'm using insert statement in SQL Server to store the text.

Comment: Can you show that? You may actually store *corrupted* text.